# on prem SharePoint 2013 size limitations

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am attempting to provide some of my remote users (bandwidth limited) with a on prem sharepoint server (Sharepoint 2013 foundation) on a Dell poweredge t110 II running windows server 2012 r2 standard.

I saw in the spec that the free version of sql supports up to 10gb

My question is does that mean total data or is that just 10gb of pointer data that points to the sharepoint blob

I am looking at about 500gb of data over the course of 2-3 years for this project I won't want to find one year into this that i've painted myself into a corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 10 GB size limit applies to the database size and each SharePoint site collection can be stored in separate database. So as long as you aren't hosting the data on the site itself you might be ok. However to do that can be tricky, I believe what you would need to do is have an ADFS server (which you will want to provide a better sign in experience for you remote users anyway). And you use ADFS to pass the authentication tokens over to your file server, which could then serve the data up through SharePoint, maybe. Would take some serious customization to make it work.

However you will be running into the hard limits of SQL Express which is 1 GB of RAM, and 1 CPU. SharePoint is entirely database driven, and requires a minimum 8 GB of RAM and 4 cores for the SQL server just to function correctly.

In short, it MAY be possible, but it will run poorly and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: exactly what I needed to know. unfortunate but better to know it now than when I hit 9.9 gigs